# Swift: How to use response from SocketIO emitWithAck method

Tags: json, swift, socket.io, jsondecoder

I'm using the SocketIO library to connect my iOS app to my server. 
I want to emit some data to the server and get a json dictionary back in the acknowledgment. I currently have something like this:

```
SocketHandler.mySocket.emitWithAck("my_event", [session, someInput]).timingOut(after: 3) {data in

       let myData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(myStruct.self, from: data)
```

MyStruct is defined as Class inheriting from Decodable and resembles the structure of the json I expect.

I get the following error: *Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Data'*

Any idea how I can tackle that type casting? Or would I need to go a totally other route?

(Swift 4.1 for iOS 11.3)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two things:

1. `decode(_:from:)` accepts a `Data` as a second parameter. To be able to decode from `Any` you'll need to add an extension to first serialize the data and then pass it to `JSONDecoder`, like this:

   ```
   extension Decodable {
     init(from any: Any) throws {
       let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: any)
       self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
     }
   }
   ```
2. `AckCallback`'s parameter is of an array type (i.e. `[Any]`), so you should get the first element of that array.

To make sure that you have indeed a decodable data (a dictionary or a JSON object) you can write something like this:

```
SocketHandler.mySocket.emitWithAck("my_event", [session, someInput]).timingOut(after: 3) { data in
  guard let dict = data.first as? [String: Any] else { return }
  let myData = try? myStruct(from: dict)
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! I've added
    extension Decodable {
        init(from any: Any) throws {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: any)
             self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
        }
     }
The .shared property was not found. 
When implementing the second code, I still get the same error. Would it make sense to serialize the dict directly?
I've found that the type cast to [String: Any] fails with "Invalid top-level type in JSON write". Any idea what that could be about?

Comment: @BerryBlue sorry, I forgot to remove that `shared` thing from the code. You can try the updated version now (I've simply replaced `JSONDecoder.shared` with `JSONDecoder()`). The second snippet relies on the first one so it should work once the first one is fixed.

Comment: @BerryBlue using the initializer you'll avoid repeating the serialization part every time you need to decode `Any` type.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but how do I get rid of the "Want type Data" error in the first place when I'm "just" adding an extension for Decodable?

Comment: @BerryBlue ugh, sorry, I've messed it up. Actual initialization should look like `let myData = try? myStruct(from: dict)` (where `dict` is of type `[String: Any]`). I've updated my answer in `emitWithAck` example.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else is wondering how to use SocketIO with Decodable, I created a little extension for the client to accept Decodable in the callback, based on Dan Karbayev's answer.

```swift
import Foundation
import SocketIO

extension Decodable {
  init(from any: Any) throws {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: any)
    self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
  }
}

extension SocketIOClient {

  func on<T: Decodable>(_ event: String, callback: @escaping (T)-> Void) {
    self.on(event) { (data, _) in
      guard !data.isEmpty else {
        print("[SocketIO] \(event) data empty")
        return
      }

      guard let decoded = try? T(from: data[0]) else {
        print("[SocketIO] \(event) data \(data) cannot be decoded to \(T.self)")
        return
      }

      callback(decoded)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
socket.on("location") { (data: LocationEventData) in
  // ...
}

socket.on("success") { (name: String) in
  // ...
}
```

Where `LocationEventData` and `String` are `Decodable`.